# Was Jeanne d'Arc crazy: Did Catherine of Alexandria exist according to the Catholic church?

Tags: catholicism, hagiography

I've found on atheistic site that Jeanne d'Arc was crazy, because she heard voices from Catherine of Alexandria, and that this saint never existed and was recognized as such by the Catholic church.

[Non, Mélenchon ne diffame pas Jeanne d'Arc](http://rationalisme.free.fr/melenchonjeanne.htm)

In French:

*Parmi les "voix" qu'elle entendait : sainte Catherine d’Alexandrie. Or l'Eglise a reconnu depuis que cette sainte n'avait pas existé, que c'était une légende.*

Translation, after a text explaining why she was crazy:

> Among the "voices", Ste Catherine of Alexandria, but the (Catholic) Church has since recognized that this saint did never exist, that it was only a legend.

On the other hand, the wikipedia page about this saint, or Christian sites explain the opposite. So who is right, and who is lying here?

**So, was Jeanne d'Arc crazy or a real saint?**

Considering the other points in this same French page, I will probably open another question if there's a lot to say about Saint Catherine.

Comment: I said "question for Catholic people" because it's tagged "catholic", and I'm interested in catholic answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**St. Catherine of Alexandria** is very much a recognized saint by the Catholic Church. She was taken off the the General Liturgical Calendar in 1970 due to many legends surrounding her life. But she is very much still recognized as a saint. In fact she is still listed as such in the *Roman Martyrology*, the official catalogue of saints and blesseds recognized by Rome. We celebrated her feast day on November 25th.

> Her principal symbol is the spiked wheel, which has become known as the Catherine wheel, and her feast day is celebrated on 25 November by most Christian churches. However, the Russian, Polish, Serbian and Bulgarian Orthodox Churches celebrate it on 24 November. The exact origin of this tradition is not known. In 11th-century Kyivan-Rus, the feast day was celebrated on 25 November. Saint Dimitry of Rostov in his Kniga zhyttia sviatykh (Book of the Lives of the Saints), T.1 (1689) places the date of celebration on 24 November. A story that Empress Catherine the Great did not wish to share her patronal feast with the Leavetaking of the feast of the Presentation of the Theotokos and hence changed the date is not supported by historical evidence. One of the first Roman Catholic churches to be built in Russia, the Catholic Church of St. Catherine, was named after Catherine of Alexandria because she was Catherine the Great's patron. A footnote to the entry for 25 November in The Synaxarion compiled by Hieromonk Makarios of Simonos Petra states: "Until the 16th century, the memory of St Catherine was observed on 24 Nov. According to a note by Bartholomew of Koutloumousiou inserted in the Menaion, the Fathers of Sinai transferred the date to 25 Nov. in order that the feast might be kept with greater solemnity."
>
> The 1908 Catholic Encyclopedia describes her historical importance:
>
> > Ranked with St Margaret and St Barbara as one of the fourteen most helpful saints in heaven, she was unceasingly praised by preachers and sung by poets. It is believed that Jacques-Benigne Bossuet dedicated to her one of his most beautiful panegyrics and that Adam of St. Victor wrote a magnificent poem in her honour: Vox Sonora nostri chori. - [Catherine of Alexandria](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catherine_of_Alexandria)

Thus if Catherine of Alexandria is recognized as a Catholic saint, then  [Jeanne d'Arc](https://catholicsaints.info/saint-joan-of-arc/) is not crazy and is also recognized as a Catholic saint.

> One of five children born to Jacques d’Arc and Isabelle Romee. Shepherdess. Mystic. From age 13 she received visions from Saint Margaret of Antioch, Saint Catherine of Alexandria, and Michael the Archangel.
>
> In the early 15th century, England, in alliance with Burgundy, controlled most of what is modern France. In May 1428 Joan’s visions told her to find the true king of France and help him reclaim his throne. She resisted for more than three years, but finally went to Charles VII in Chinon and told him of her visions. Carrying a banner that read “Jesus, Mary”, she led troops from one battle to another. She was severely wounded, but her victories from 23 February 1429 to 23 May 1430 brought Charles VII to the throne. Captured by the Burgundians during the defence of Compiegne, she was sold to the English for 10 thousand francs. She was put on trial by an ecclesiastical court conducted by Cauchon, Bishop of Beauvais, a supporter of England, and was excuted as a heretic. In 1456 her case was re-tried, and Joan was acquitted (23 years too late).
>
> “About Jesus Christ and the Church, I simply know they’re just one thing, and we shouldn’t complicate the matter.” – Saint Joan of Arc, as recorded at her trial.

On February 14,1969 Pope Paul VI in his Moto Proprio [***Mysterii Paschalis***](http://www.vatican.va/content/paul-vi/en/motu_proprio/documents/hf_p-vi_motu-proprio_19690214_mysterii-paschalis.html) the the New Calendar would go into effect on January 1st, 1970.

> In order to execute this decision of the Ecumenical Council, the names of some saints have been removed from the universal Calendar, and the faculty has been given of re-establishing in regions concerned, if it is desired, the commemorations and cult of other saints. The suppression of reference to a certain number of saints who are not universally known has permitted the insertion, within the Roman Calendar, of names of some martyrs of regions where the proclaiming of the Gospel arrived at a later date. Thus, as representatives of their countries, those who have won renown by the shedding of their blood for Christ or by their outstanding virtues enjoy the same dignity in this same catalogue.
>
> For these reasons we think that the new universal Calendar, prepared for the Latin rite, is more in harmony with the piety and the needs of our times, and that it better reflects the universality of the Church, in the sense that it proposes the names of the most important saints, who present to all the People of God a shining example of sanctity in a variety of ways. It is superfluous to say that this will contribute to the spiritual well-being of the entire Christian world.

Comment: Once again, the atheists cited in the question seem to be spreading misinformation.  Gee, there's a surprise.

Comment: I suppose we'll have to answer the same question about St. John Vianney and St. Philomena and [Tommie Connor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Saw_Mommy_Kissing_Santa_Claus) and St. Nicholas.

Comment: Many thanks Ken! I was in doubt, because I saw this info echoed even by some uninformed Christian sites. There are more, I will probably open other questions with the other claims, because there is much to say.